# Finding easiest way of using api data to allow users to select specific parts, and save to other database

Tags: vb.net

Hey so I'm doing a school project and I decided to do this yugioh (a card game) deck builder project, using a card database provided here: https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api-guide/

I've downloaded a json file that contains all the contents of their api and I've been trying to learn to desterialize the contents of the api, but I've been really struggling in finding assistance (yes I've tried newtonsoft and other websites but I just don't understand their examples and they aren't similar to the one I use.) Whilst a youtube video did teach me how to desterealize one part of the json file, like this for example:

```
{
"id": "101009033",
"name": "Beat Raptor",
"type": "Effect Monster",
"desc": "While this card is in the Main Monster Zone, negate the effects of monsters while they are in the Extra Monster Zones. When this card is destroyed by battle: You can Special Summon 1 \"Beat Raptor\" from your Deck. You can only use this effect of \"Beat Raptor\" once per turn. ",
"atk": "1400",
"def": "2000",
"level": "4",
"race": "Dinosaur",
"attribute": "EARTH",
"image_url": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics/101009033.jpg",
"image_url_small": "https://storage.googleapis.com/ygoprodeck.com/pics_small/101009033.jpg"
}
```

my json file contains thousands of them and so far I haven't been able to find something that allows me to understand how to print specific cards (for example when a person searches for "Dark Magician" the contents of that card are printed, let alone save the user's choice in a seperate database.)

So I'm just wondering if you would know any easier ways to achieve my goal (ultimately of allowing users to search for a card, select one and save it to a database.) Maybe using an sql server instead of a json file (as I have found more videos on that) sticking to apis, json or something new for example. Honestly I have put in effort and I'm willing to learn, but I just can't find things that will walk me through using something like json or apis that allow me to achieve my goal whilst still being understandable.

Thankyou for your patience

Comment: So, at this time, you need help with what, specifically? Can't be everything, a SO answer can't hold an encyclopedia.

Comment: Maybe you should read up on that API a bit better. The first two parameters it says that it supports are "name" to search for an exact name and "fname" to search for a partial name. That's how you allow your user to search, not by downloading everything and then searching through it yourself.

Comment: Also, if you are getting a result with multiple instances of the same set of data then that is going to correspond to an array or collection in your .NET types, so you can look for information on deserializing lists/collections/arrays. Basically, you just have to define an appropriate type in your .NET code and specify that type when deserializing and all the data mapping should happen automatically.

Comment: yeah thanks again jmcilhinney I'll see if I can find a different type of list to deserialize, as although json works I just can't understand online samples and I can't find much walkthroughs on how to use it either so I'll see if I can find one that I can learn easier.

Comment: A JSON can be easily deserialized using standard classes. It then depends on what you want to do with this data. Do you want to store it? You can write the JSON to a file, use a database, isolated storage, many options. Should the database be *portable* (single file)? Are you planning on keeping those Bitmaps around? Do you just need to download updates? I looks like you're missing a plan, by now, maybe more than technical stuff.

Comment: Yeah no worries thanks Jimi for your advice! I think I will stick to JSON it sounds like it can do everything I want (yeah I was looking to store it in both a database and a file), now I just need to find a way to learn how to do it...

Comment: Test something (many resources in SO), then make a specific question about deserializing/serializing a JSON, if something is not clear. If/when you do, post a correct JSON (simplified, but complete), not just a piece of it. It's important to suggest the correct way to handle it.

Comment: Yep yep thanks we'll try learning specific things and see how we go!